# Let agents follow its neighbour but got the error "FACE expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead."

Tags: if-statement, hyperlink, netlogo

I try to move each agents to its related agents (defined by high trust connection and in my view) if there are any such agents, and else move the agent to one of its neighbours. However, I get the error "FACE expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead." and I don't know how to solve it. I think the use != nobody might cause the error. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

This is my code:

```
breed [ persons a-person ]

undirected-link-breed [ connections connection ]
connections-own [ trust ]

persons-own [ neighbours ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-persons 10
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  setup-connections
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-connections
  ask persons 
  [  
    create-connections-with other persons 
    [ set trust 0.6 ] 
  ]
end

to go
  setNeighbours
  movePersons
  tick
end

to setNeighbours
  ask persons [ set neighbours other persons in-cone 4 360 ]
end

to movePersons
  ask persons
  [
    let highlyRelatedPersons (turtle-set [other-end] of my-out-connections with [trust = 0.6]) in-cone 4 360
    let relatedPersons (turtle-set [other-end] of my-out-connections with [trust = 0.6])
    ifelse any? highlyRelatedPersons
    [ 
      face one-of highlyRelatedPersons
    ]
    [ 
      let weaklyRelatedNeighbour one-of neighbours with [not member? self highlyRelatedPersons] ;select one of my neighbours that is not a highlyRelatedPerson
      ifelse weaklyRelatedNeighbour != nobody
      [
        face weaklyRelatedNeighbour
      ]
      [
        face one-of relatedPersons
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Is there any code missing here? And did you actually test the code you wrote here?
1. You define a link breed but never actually create any links.
2. You wrote `reset ticks` instead of `reset-ticks`.
3. You didn't define `neighbours`.
4. You wrote `highlyRelated` instead of `highlyRelatedPersons` somewhere in `move-Persons`

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes in my code, I have corrected it. However, there is highRelated and highlyRelatedPersons, which are two different agentsets and I cannot find highlyRelated anywhere in my code.

Comment: Ooh ok, yeah that's why it is important to provide a chunk of code that can work where all parameters are clearly defined on this website. Otherwise the people helping get confused what things are supposed to do or mean.
Regarding highlyRelated in your code, I editted your code since I assumed it was a spelling error (after a certain level of activity you can edit questions of other people).

Comment: There are places where you use one-of to get a turtle from a set. But you don’t test with “any?” To ensure the set has members, not test  one-of hasn’t returned ‘nobody’. This suggests you are sure those sets have members…but clearly they dont. Either add tests to avoid acting on nobody, or figure out why those sets don’t have members.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in what is causing the error
`highlyRelatedPersons` is an agentset and while an agentset can be empty, an agentset can never be `nobody`. `one-of highlyRelatedPersons` however, will be `nobody` if the agentset is empty, so you could use `ifelse (one-of highlyRelatedPersons != nobody)`.
That said, is easier to just check if the agentset is empty by using `any?`:
`ifelse any? highlyRelatedPersons`

Your code also never actually creates any links for `highlyRelatedPersons` and `relatedPersons` is always empty. This means that the code will always return false on the first ifelse and move on to the second. Generally most turtles will have neighbours they can face, but sometimes there are none so they try to  `face one-of relatedPersons`, which again causes a crash since `relatedPersons` is an empty agentset.

Comment: @Flo2000 relatedPersons was an empty agentset because relatedPersons was defined based on the links. Once you have links, it should no longer be empty

Comment: @Flo2000 what exactly is your goal with  `[not member? one-of neighbours highlyRelatedPersons]`? Currently it checks if one of the neighbours of your neighbours is part of highlyRelatedPersons.
Perhaps you mean to use [not member? self highlyRelatedPersons]? 
In this specific case, you could even just drop the entire `with` block. After all, you only come to this point if there are no highlyRelatedPersons so there is no need to check if the neighbours fall into that category (although this might lead to problems if you further alter the code)